# cypress 12.17.0 preserve the session across Specs

Tags: cypress

I'm using **cypress 12.17.0**. I need to do login in the **before** fuction and preserve the session through the specs.

The official doc [Caching-session-data-across-specs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Caching-session-data-across-specs) says I can use '**cacheAcrossSpecs**' property but it doesn't working for me.

This is my spec file:

```
describe('Testing session persistence', () => {
    before(() => {
        let url = '/';
        let username = 'my_user';
        let pass = 'user_pass';

        cy.session(
            'session_test', 
            () => {
            cy.visit(url)
            cy.get('#username').type(username);
            cy.get('#password').type(pass);
            cy.get('#acceptButton').click();
            cy.getCookie('PHPSESSID').should('exist');
            },
            {
                cacheAcrossSpecs: true,
            }
        )
    })

    it('Test 1: Check anything', () => {        
        //it works well
        cy.visit('/');
        cy.url().should('not.contain', '/login')
    });

    it('Test 2: Other action', () => {
        //it doesn't work, it's redirecting to login
        cy.visit('/');
        cy.url().should('not.contain', '/login')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cacheAcrossSpecs` flag won't help you in this example, it's for caching across ... ***specs***.

`cy.session()` will cache across your ***tests*** if you use a `beforeEach()` hook instead of a `before()`.

The reason is, `cy.session()` must actually be called before it can apply it's caching feature. That will only happen on a per-test basis using 'beforeEach()`.

Also, `cy.getCookie('PHPSESSID').should('exist')` looks like something you would put into the validation function, as it will invalidate the cache and re-run the setup function should the cookie expire during the test.

See [Examples - with validation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Examples)